# How to assign each line in a text file to an array in PL/SQL?

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I have text file in unix shell script. I am connecting DB from the shell script itself. So, I want to assign each line in a text file to array in pl/sql?

My text file contains below contents.

```
1121212
343433
3434344
```

How to assign each line in a text to an array in PL/SQL?

I need a output below output.

```
array array_t := array_t('1121212', '343433', '3434344');
```

Comment: PL/SQL arrays are usually tables or collections. I think you want tables. Check out a PL/SQL table here: http://comsci.liu.edu/~vasilaky/db2/tables.htm  -- Your question cannot be answered as you have posted it, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of loading data from a file into the database is to use an external table.  This is a database structure which we can query with SELECT statements but where the table comes from an OS file. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011).

Using that approach you could populate your array like this:

```
select * 
bulk collect into l_array
from your_ext_table;
```

Although, as you can access the data directly, through the external table, perhaps you don't need the array after all.

A slower way to achieve the same thing would be to read your file with UTL_FILE.  [Find our more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069).

```
declare
     fh utl_file.file_handle;
     l_array array_t := new array_t();
     l_str varchar2(4000);
     l_cnt simple_integer := 0;
begin
     fh := utl_file.fopen('YOUR_DB_DIR', 'your_os_file.txt', 'r');
     loop
         utl_file.get_line(fh, l_str);
         l_array.extend();
         l_cnt := l_cnt+1;
         l_array(l_cnt) := to_number(l_str);
     end loop;
exception
     when no_data_found then
        utl_file.fclose(fh);
end;
```

There is no simple way of producing output like this from a text file with values:

```
array array_t := array_t('1121212', '343433', '3434344');
```

It would require dynamic SQL, and there's no value in doing that when the same outcome can be achieved with much more straightforward approaches.

---

Likewise, using a shell script is a clunky way of executing PL/SQL.  You should write stored procedures and run them from within the database.  Even if you must use shell scripts for triggering the database calls (why?  it's almost 2015 already) you should put as much of the logic as possible into stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must load from a file into an array then...

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    DECLARE
        TYPE names IS VARRAY(1000) OF VARCHAR2(255);
        surnames names := names();
    
        FUNCTION loadFromFile(directoryIN VARCHAR2, filename IN VARCHAR2) 
        RETURN names 
        IS
            results names := names();
            ifile UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
            str VARCHAR2(255);
            counter INTEGER := 0;
        BEGIN 
    
/*

The first parameter for UTL_FILE.OPEN is an entry in dba_directories created...
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY CUSTOM_SCRIPT AS '/opt/oracle/oradata/Custom Scripts';

...and here's what you get for your money...
SQL> SELECT * FROM dba_directories WHERE directory_name = 'CUSTOM_SCRIPT';

*/

            ifile := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(directory, filename, 'R');
    
            LOOP
                -- need to handle the EOF exception
                BEGIN
                    UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(ifile, str);
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                        EXIT;
                END;
                counter := counter + 1;
                results.extend;
                results(counter) := str;
            END LOOP;
    
            UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(ifile);
    
            RETURN results;
    
        END;
    
    BEGIN
    
        -- load names from file
        surnames := loadFromFile('CUSTOM_SCRIPT', 'surnames.txt');
    
        FOR indx IN 1..surnames.COUNT LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(surnames(indx));
        END LOOP;
    
    END; 
    /
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion as a workaround you should create a control file and load the data into a temporary table from your text file and then you can use the bulk collect into to load the data into the array.